# Send values from an javascript array into form value html, to send the values in an html value to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, forms

Difficult title, let me explain

I have values in an javascript array, and I want to put these values into a form wich gets readed in PHP.

I was thinking something like this:

Result.title = the array with the titles filled in by the user.
Result.price = the array with the prices filled in from the database

```
*the html*
<textarea id="products" type="hidden" name="products"/> 
<textarea id="price_products" type="hidden" name="price_products"/> 



*the javascripts*
$("#products").val(result.title);
$("#price_products").val(result.price);


*the PHP*
$products = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['products']));
$price_products = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['price_products']));

$Body .= $products;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $price_products;
$Body .= "\n";
```

The problem with this is that I'm only sending the first value to the textarea.

Comment: either your "result" is a single item, or you need a loop to grab multiple items. Are the products/prices an array? would it be possible to execute foreach (result.title) { perform action }

Comment: Can you please show them in their own places and not all the 3 languages' code extracts?

Comment: You have to loop through all the results and append the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you're using PHP on the server-side, you can use hidden fields with a `[]` suffix in the field name.

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
<script>
var items = ["Hello","World"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    document.write('<input type="hidden" name="items[]" value="'+escape(items[i])+'" />')
}
</script>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then, in `post.php`, just read `$_POST['items']`, which will be an array.

Comment: Its not an array in the post.php, it only gives the last value!

Comment: You're sure you put `[]` at the end of the `name`? Hasn't failed me since PHP 4-ish.

Comment: you're right, it is returning an array right now, (php noob here), any tips converting this array into readable object to deliver in a mail?

Edit: "Results: " . print_r( $items, true );worked for me, thanks!